# How to access wooCommerce config for cuustom WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Maybe this is already answered somewhere else, but I couldn't find it after researching for 5 days.

I've a custom WP Query that returns products for JavaScript AJAX client. My client wants to handle the "number of rows" and "columns" through wooCommerce config that is available through customization of shop page. [image][image]

Here's my basic implementation for custom WP Query:

```php
function loadProducts(){
  // Access the number of rows and columns input here from customization page??
}
add_action("wp_ajax_loadprods","loadProducts");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_loadprods","loadProducts")
```

Comment: Ref: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`
Columns => `$columns = get_option( 'woocommerce_catalog_columns', 4 );`
$rows => `$rows         = absint( get_option( 'woocommerce_catalog_rows', 4 ) );`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'll mark this as the solution if you write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ref: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`

```php
function loadProducts(){
    $columns = get_option('woocommerce_catalog_columns', 4); 
    $rows = absint(get_option('woocommerce_catalog_rows', 4));
    
    echo json_encode(array('columns' => $columns, 'rows' => $rows));

    wp_die();
}
add_action("wp_ajax_loadprods","loadProducts");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_loadprods","loadProducts")
```